# How to calculate the edge attributes as the path length in igraph?

Tags: r, path, attributes, igraph, edge-list

Pretend the dataframe below is an edgelist (relation between inst2 and motherinst2), and that km is an attribute I want to calculate as a path that's been assigned to the edges. I'm too new at coding to make a reproducible edge list.

```
inst2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
motherinst2 = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11) 
km = c(20, 30, 40, 25, 60)
df2 = data.frame(inst2, motherinst2)
edgelist = cbind(df2, km)
g = graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)
```

I know how to calculate the path length of vertices in a graph, but I have some attributes attached to the edges that I want to sum up as path lengths. They are simple attributes (distance in km, time in days, and speed as km/day).

This is how I was calculating the path of vertices (between roots and terminals/leaves):

```
roots = which(sapply(sapply(V(g),
                    function(x) neighbors(g, x, mode = 'in')), length) == 0)

#slight tweaking this piece of code will also calculate 'terminal' nodes (or leaves). (11):

terminals = which(sapply(sapply(V(g),
                    function(x) neighbors(g, x, mode = 'out')), length) == 0)


paths= lapply(roots, function(x) get.all.shortest.paths(g, from = x, to = terminals, mode = "out")$res)

named_paths= lapply(unlist(paths, recursive=FALSE), function(x) V(g)[x])
```

I just want to do essentially exactly as I did above, but summing up the distance, time, and rate (which I will compute the mean of) incurred between each of those paths. If it helps to know how the edges have been added as attributes, I've used cbind like so:

```
edgelist_df = cbind(edgelist_df, time, dist, speed)
```

and my graph object (g) is set up like this:

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist_df, vertices = vattrib_df)
```

vattrib_df is the attributes of the vertices, which is not of interest to us here.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output so that possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: Hm. The trouble is I am new to R and I'm not sure how to go about producing a sample edgelist. Mine is based on a dataframe of 266 observations. I'm just looking for the edge attributes along a path to be added together and return a sum.

Comment: Maybe make a fake dataframe with 5 observations? The more simple the example, the better.

Comment: Just a dataframe? I genuinely can't figure out how to make an edgelist from a dataframe. Mine was set up for me from a pile of observations (266).